# PsExec on two XP machines says "Access Denied"

Tags: windows-xp, psexec

I have two XP machines and I have the following situation.

1. I am running psexec from comp1
2. comp2 does not have any password
3. My bat file command

   ```
   psexec -i -d -c \\comp2 c:\xyz.exe
   ```

The error message I get is

> Couldn't access comp2: Access Denied

I also added new user 'test' with password 'abcd' on comp2 and logged in then from comp1. I gave command

```
psexec -i -d -c \\comp2 -u test -p abcd c:\xyz.exe
```

but the error remains the same. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using XP Home by chance? According to the Sysinternals Forums [here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic15919.html), one of requirements for psexec is check the target machine to make sure it's not running Windows XP Home because it lacks the network functionality required by (most) PSTools commands. The issue with XP Home was also investigated in detail in this [thread](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-access-is-denied_topic547_page3.html) from the same forum.